# Slick thumbnail slider currently change on thumbnail focus need on hover as well

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

Hellow everyone. Good day. I have tried slick slider to make a slider animation. I want to change the main image on the hover of its thumbnail. I want to ask that is it possible? I added my code in codepen link ([codepan](https://codepen.io/Designer12/pen/jOqXzQg?editors=1000)) so please check this link. Thanks in advance. Try this link because it is showing error so I share my code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.slider-for').slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: false,
          fade: true,
          asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
      });
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
          slidesToShow: 6,
          slidesToScroll: 1,

          asNavFor: '.slider-for',
          dots: false,
          focusOnSelect: true,
          responsive: [{
                  breakpoint: 992,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 768,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 580,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                      slidesToShow: 3,
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 380,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                      slidesToShow: 2,
                  }
              }
          ]
      });
  });
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
 <section class="banner-section">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="vehicle-detail-banner banner-content clearfix">
           <div class="banner-slider">
               <div class="slider slider-for">
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="slider slider-nav thumb-image">
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day, yes you can change the slick slider one hovering on the thumbnail. You can call a mouseover function to your slick-slide. create a condition that if the mouse hovers on slick nav(thumbnail) change the currently active target. Hope this will help you. I edited your code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.slider-for').slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: false,
          fade: true,
          asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
      });
      //set active class to first slide
$('.slider-nav .slick-slide').eq(0).addClass('slick-active');
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
          slidesToShow: 6,
          slidesToScroll: 1,

          asNavFor: '.slider-for',
          dots: false,
          focusOnSelect: true,
          responsive: [{
                  breakpoint: 992,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 768,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 580,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                      slidesToShow: 3,
                  }
              },
              {
                  breakpoint: 380,
                  settings: {
                      vertical: false,
                      slidesToShow: 2,
                  }
              }
          ]
      });
      $('.slider-nav').on('mouseover', '.slick-slide', function (e) {
        var $currTarget = $(e.currentTarget), 
        index = $currTarget.data('slick-index'),
        slickObj = $('.slider-for').slick('getSlick');
    
    slickObj.slickGoTo(index);
    
});
  });
```

```css
.banner-slider .slider.slider-for {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.banner-slider .slider.slider-nav {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.banner-slider .slider.slider-for,
.banner-slider .slider.slider-nav {
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-slider .slider.slider-for{
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.banner-slider .slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-slider .slider-banner-image {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-slider .slider.slider-nav {
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}
.banner-slider .slider-nav .slick-slide.thumbnail-image .thumbImg img {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.banner-slider .slider-banner-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.banner-slider .slick-vertical .slick-slide:active,
.banner-slider .slick-vertical .slick-slide:focus,
.banner-slider .slick-arrow:hover,
.banner-slider .slick-arrow:focus {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
.banner-slider .slider-nav .slick-slide.slick-current span {
    color: #196DB6;
}
.banner-slider .slider-nav .slick-slide {
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-slider .slider-nav .slick-slide span {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 15px;
}
.banner-slider .slick-arrow {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.slick-prev {
   top: 0;
}
.slick-next {
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #fff;
}
.banner-slider .slider.slider-nav .thumbImg {
    padding: 0 5px 15px;
}
.slider-nav .slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active .thumbImg img {
    border: 1px solid #80D6CF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 3px;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 991px) {
    .banner-slider .slider.slider-for,
    .banner-slider .slider.slider-nav {
        max-width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    .banner-slider .slider.slider-for {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .banner-slider .slider.slider-nav {
        height: auto;
    }
    .slider-banner-image {
        height: 500px;
    }
    .slider.slider-nav.thumb-image {
        padding: 10px 30px 0;
    }
    .slider-nav .slick-slide span {
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    .slick-arrow {
        padding: 0;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        top: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    }
    .slick-prev {
        left: 0;
        right: unset;
    }
    .slick-next {
        left: unset;
        right: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .vehicle-detail-banner .car-slider-desc {
        max-width: 340px;
    }
    .bid-tag {
        padding: 10px 0 15px;
    }
    .slider.slider-nav.thumb-image {
       white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .thumbnail-image.slick-slide {
        padding: 0px 5px;
        min-width: 75px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width : 767px) {
    .slider-banner-image {
        height: 400px;
    }
    .slider.slider-nav.thumb-image {
        padding: 0px 20px 0;
        margin: 10px 0px 0;
    }
    .slider-nav .slick-slide.thumbnail-image .thumbImg {
        max-width: 140px;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .slick-prev.slick-arrow {
        background-position: center 10px;
    }
    .slick-next.slick-arrow {
        background-position: center 10px, center;
    }
    .slider-nav .slick-slide span {
        font-size: 12px;
        white-space: normal;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<section class="banner-section">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="vehicle-detail-banner banner-content clearfix">
           <div class="banner-slider">
               <div class="slider slider-for">
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
                   <div class="slider-banner-image">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="Car-Image">
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="slider slider-nav thumb-image">
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570942872213-1242607a35eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570171278960-d6c2b316f3b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="thumbnail-image">
                       <div class="thumbImg">
                           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564376130023-5360fbb7c91b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=724&q=80" alt="slider-img">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: if it works for you then marked this as your answer so that others don't give any answer

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: https://ibb.co/R0Mg4XZ you can view the image in given link

Comment: you can found it on top of the left of this answer

Comment: please also marked as an answer to your question so that your question will be marked as solved. Click on that tickmark. So that if any contributor comes to your question with the same problem he can found this answer. welcome